# Set Custom Mouse Cursor in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

following is my flex 3 code.

[Embed(source="SizeNESW.png")]
   [Bindable]
   public var cursor:Class;

private function mouseOver():void
   {
       CursorManager.setCursor(cursor);
   }

here what i am doing that there are four corners above the image for resizing purpose. and i have a single image for cursor. i want to use that image for all corners of the image. i.e i need to rotate that cursor image for different corners.

ne help i m stuck :(

Comment: So what's the problem? You don't know how to rotate, or your cursor doesn't show up?

Comment: the rotation property is not working.

Comment: what i was thinking that before setting value to setCursor function i did rotate cursor by 90 degree as cursor.rotation = 90; but its not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to create four copies of rotated image with BitmapData.draw (using rotated matrix). Note that CursorManager.setCursor returns int - you'll need it to remove custom cursor.

Comment: can i draw Bitmap from cursor Class?

Comment: You embed PNG, so it is image: var bitmap:Bitmap = new cursor as Bitmap;